# VB.NET: How init bool array with true

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initialization

Is it possible create and initialize  array of boolean with True in vb.net at one action (without cycle assignement)? 
By default array initialized by False. I need opposing.

Comment: Is a `For Each` not an option?

Comment: @DDD Soft, No, it is not an option. I want shortest syntax.

Comment: Why is it so important to have the "shortest syntax"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) which support only True and False. The constructor let you initialize it.

```
Dim b As New BitArray(1000, True)

Console.WriteLine(b(10)) ' Display True
```

It should take less memory also.

Comment: Oh, great! I didn't think about it! That's seems like the best solution for me! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq method [Repeat(Of TResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve such task in the shortest way, without defining any custom function.

```
Dim myArray = Enumerable.Repeat(Of Boolean)(True, 10000).ToArray()
```

Comment: Ok, that's the solution. But, it works much more slowly than for...next. It's pitty that .NET not allows initialize boolean arrays with all values are equals true without any tricks. Thank You!

Comment: You can define an Extension method bound to type **Boolean()**, and perform the much faster for..next-based initialization from such method. That would be the shortest and fastest solution.

Comment: Nice idea, i'll try.